# Use jQuery to get a specific CSS class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an element with some CSS rules applied as follows:

```
<span class="rule1 rule2 rule3[foo/bar]"></span>
```

I can use jQuery to retrieve the full class list using:

```
var classes = $("span").attr('css');
```

How do I select a specific rule, in this case rule3 complete with its array contents?

Comment: A class name with array contents? That kind of notation is new to me. Where do you have it from? And what do you mean by "select" - do you want to determine whether a specific link has this class?

Comment: Select as in grab rule3 and therefore be able to use the contents of the square brackets in a script. I've inherited the class rules & it's too late to change them all to use jQuery data() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do..

```
var arr = $('span').attr('class').split(" ");
```

And then iterate over them as you wish..  `arr[i]`

Comment: But I agree with Peeter. Using jQuery's `.data()` would be a much more efficient practice.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use a *css class* to store information. jQuery offers the feature to store all kinds of data into `data-XXX` propertys which in turn, are pulled into jQuerys *.data() expando* propertys.

In your example, this could look like

```
<span data-rules='{"rule1":"foo","rule2":"bar","rule3":"baz"}'></span>
```

This is a JSON-stringified version of your logic. By querying that node with jQuery like

```
var myspan = $('span');
```

you can now access this data attribute by calling

```
myspan.data('rules').rule3 // === "baz"
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/data/ (section: HTML 5 data- Attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I'd considering using the html5 data attribute instead.

Read up on http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$('span[class~="rule1"]')
```

also you can try this one;

```
$('span.rule1')
```